# Convert a timezone value to datetime and insert

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I'm having trouble inserting a field into the database, type conversion keeps timezone

```
UPDATE order o
SET o.data_envio = CONVERT( '2022-01-05T14:47:00-03:00', DATETIME );
```

1292 - Truncated incorrect datetime value: '2022-01-05T14:47:00-03:00'

Comment: Are you sure o.data_envio is of type 'DATETIME'?

Answer (score 0):

This requires mysql 8; it will not work on 5.7 or earlier, or any version of mariadb (through at least 10.7.1).

Instead, you can do:

```
SET o.data_envio = convert_tz('2022-01-05T14:47:00','-03:00','+00:00')
```

Note that the first parameter cannot have the offset; it has to just be provided as the second parameter.  If you have to remove it in your sql, not your code, and your dates are always well formed (no missing - or :, always two digits for each part except four for year), you can do:

```
UPDATE `order` o SET o.data_envio = CONVERT_TZ(
    SUBSTRING('2022-01-05T14:47:00-03:00' FROM 1 FOR 19),
    SUBSTRING('2022-01-05T14:47:00-03:00' FROM 20),
    '+00:00'
)
```

Comment: UPDATE vendas v  SET v.data_envio = convert_tz( '2018-01-30T12:00:00-03:00', '-03:00', '+00:00' ) WHEREv.id_venda = 525816

error UPDATE vendas v set v.data_envio = convert_tz('2018-01-30T12:00:00-03:00','-03:00','+00:00') where v.id_venda = 525816
> 1292 - Truncated incorrect datetime value: '2018-01-30T12:00:00-03:00'
> Time: 0,036s

Comment: @ElvisReis yes, you can't have the offset on the datetime, you have to have it just as the second parameter to convert_tz.  is it always -03:00?

Answer (score 0):

You want to convert the timestamp with the `STR_TO_DATE()` function:

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/str_to_date/

Like this:

```sql
   UPDATE order o
   SET o.data_envio = STR_TO_DATE( '2022-01-05T14:47:00-03:00', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:%s')
```

Only drawback here is that you will lose the timezone information.

Comment: in strict mode, the offset at the end will make this fail with "Truncated incorrect datetime value" just like the convert did.  if they want to ignore the offset, they'd have to explicitly do that with the format `'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:%s%.%#:%#'`  [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.6&fiddle=4279f905584a2447e202bfbcd9341001)